# Rails 5: After Ajax Operation, Javascript Code Being Displayed On Page

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm working on a remote operation in my rails app.  The destroy method behavior works correctly.  The issue is the javascript code appears on the page afterwards. I need to know why the behavior is occurring, and what I need to do to fix it.

destroy method in controller:

```
def destroy
  @payee = Payee.find(params[:id])
  @payee.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @payee, notice: 'Person was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.js
    format.json { render json: @payee, location: @payee }
  end
end
```

payee.coffee: handles ajax request:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $("#payees").on("ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#payees").append xhr.responseText).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
      $("#payees").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

destroy.js.coffee

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@payee) %>').fadeOut ->
  $(this).remove()
```

my payee partial:

```
<tr id="<%= dom_id(payee)%>">
<td><%= payee.company %></td>
  <td><%= payee.first_name %></td>
  <td><%= payee.last_name %></td>
  <td><%= link_to '<i class="link green large edit icon"></i>'.html_safe, edit_payee_path(payee.id), remote: true %></td>
  <td><%= link_to '<i class="link red large remove icon"></i>'.html_safe, payee_path(payee), method: :delete, remote: true %></td>
</tr>
```

Here's images showing the behavior before Insurance Company Record is deleted.

[image: Before The Record is deleted]

After the Insurance Company record is deleted:

[image: After Record is Deleted]

EDIT:

create code as requested

create.js.coffee

```
$("<%= escape_javascript(render @payee )%>").prependTo("#payees")
$('#new_payee')[0].reset()
```

create method in controller

```
def create
  @payee = Payee.new(payee_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @payee.save
      format.html { redirect_to @payee, notice: 'Payee was successfully created.' }
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @payee, status: :created, location: @payee }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @payee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Everything else is the same

Edit 2:

not sure why this worked but I removed all arguments out of the success function.

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  $("#payees").on("ajax:success", () ->
    $("#payees").append xhr.responseText).on "ajax:error", (e, xhr, status, error) ->
      $("#payees").append "<p>ERROR</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

From your `payee.coffee` code: when you have an `ajax:success` event (your remote delete) you append the response to `#payees` dom element.

Comment: I do the same thing for the create action and I don't get the same behavior

Comment: Does my answer fix your first issue ? For your second issue, how do you call your create action ? Are you sure it's by ajax ?

Comment: I think I get it : I'm not a jquery expert, but maybe you do not observe the same behavior with the create because your ajax:success event is bound to the #payess selector. Therefore, it's not triggered when you create because it's not in the #payess dom tree ?

Comment: Very well could be.  in fact I'm almost certain. I'm going to fiddle a bit.

Comment: I got it working by taking the arguments out of the success function.  Now I only append the element on error.  Not sure what ramifications my "fix" will have down the road. I updated question to show

Comment: obviously, il you remove the xhr argument, in the end you are appending nothing to your dom element...

Comment: just remove the ajax:success event (that does nothing now) and handle the ajax:error path